# How do I change the default hyperlink color?

Tags: themes

I like dark background, light text layouts.  However, it is still making hyperlinks dark blue, which makes them very hard to read.

Here's a screenshot.  The program is Zim, but the color scheme is the same by most programs.

[image: Example]

Is there a way to change that?  Is this something that I can set in the theme?  I'm using a theme called Giungla.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your `~/.config/zim/style.conf`(copy if from `/usr/share/zim/style.conf`) change it from blue to whatever suits you.  Reference [here](http://zim-wiki.org/manual/Help/Config_Files.html).

```
[Tag link]
foreground = blue
#underline  = single
```

Answer (score 4):

```
vim ~/.config/zim/style.conf
```

Change color

```
    [Tag link]
foreground = light blue
```

light blue looks better  :)

[image]

Comment: You can also do hex numbers directly, for instance a specific light blue like `#36e4ff` from a [color picker](https://www.google.com/search?q=color+picker&oq=color+picker&aqs=chrome..69i57j0i512j0i433i512j0i512j0i433i512l2j0i512l2j0i433i512.1658j0j7&client=ubuntu&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)